# Token is not validating on lambda console using Spring OAuth2 and Azure AD

Tags: aws-lambda, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-spring-cloud

I am using spring OAuth2 with Azure AD to authenticate APIs which is working on local server but when I am running application on AWS lambda i am always getting 401. I don't know what I am missing. Attaching logs from localhost and AWS server for your reference:

**Logs from localhost:**

2023-02-22 14:11:53.105 INFO 14964 --- [ main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Starting service [Tomcat] 2023-02-22 14:11:53.105 INFO 14964 --- [ main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.62] 2023-02-22 14:11:53.312 INFO 14964 --- [ main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext 2023-02-22 14:11:53.312 INFO 14964 --- [ main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2061 ms 2023-02-22 14:11:53.417 DEBUG 14964 --- [ main] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('APPROLE_ADMIN')") 2023-02-22 14:11:53.420 DEBUG 14964 --- [ main] m.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource : with attributes [[authorize: 'hasAuthority('APPROLE_ADMIN')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']] 2023-02-22 14:11:53.608 DEBUG 14964 --- [ main] swordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder : No authenticationProviders and no parentAuthenticationManager defined. Returning null. inside OAuth2 getting outside OAuth2 2023-02-22 14:11:53.821 DEBUG 14964 --- [ main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [authenticated] for any request 2023-02-22 14:11:53.829 INFO 14964 --- [ main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5af5d76f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@61a2aeb7, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6042d663, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@abad89c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1775c4e7, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@23ad71bf, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5f8d9767, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1980a3f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3a8cea24, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7a682d35, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@61ff6a49, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6fe595dc] 2023-02-22 14:11:54.471 INFO 14964 --- [ main] c.a.c.i.jackson.JacksonVersion : Package versions: jackson-annotations=2.13.2, jackson-core=2.13.2, jackson-databind=2.13.3, jackson-dataformat-xml=2.13.2, jackson-datatype-jsr310=2.13.2, azure-core=1.26.0, Troubleshooting version conflicts: https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/dependency/troubleshoot 2023-02-22 14:11:54.611 INFO 14964 --- [ main] AbstractAzureServiceClientBuilderFactory : Will configure the default credential of type DefaultAzureCredential for class com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder. 2023-02-22 14:11:54.901 INFO 14964 --- [ main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '' 2023-02-22 14:11:54.923 INFO 14964 --- [ main] : Started in 4.4 seconds (JVM running for 5.241) 2023-02-22 14:18:26.550 INFO 14964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2023-02-22 14:18:26.551 INFO 14964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2023-02-22 14:18:26.553 INFO 14964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Completed initialization in 2 ms 2023-02-22 14:18:26.576 DEBUG 14964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy : Securing GET / 2023-02-22 14:18:26.585 DEBUG 14964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext 2023-02-22 14:18:27.540 DEBUG 14964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider : Authenticated token 2023-02-22 14:18:27.541 DEBUG 14964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .o.s.r.w.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@4ff204a1, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[SCOPE_access_as_user]] 2023-02-22 14:18:27.556 DEBUG 14964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor : Authorized filter invocation [GET /] with attributes [authenticated] 2023-02-22 14:18:27.557 DEBUG 14964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy : Secured GET / org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@4ff204a1 2023-02-22 14:18:27.699 DEBUG 14964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request

**Logs from AWS:**

Copy 2023-02-22 11:18:48.933 DEBUG 8 --- [ main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [authenticated] for any request

Copy 2023-02-22 11:18:49.055 INFO 8 --- [ main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@57ac5227, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@bf1ec20, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@38f116f6, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@736d6a5c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7fe7c640, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@4795ded0, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@b70da4c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@435fb7b5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4ba302e0, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@c5ee75e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@424fd310, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@43aaf813]

Copy 2023-02-22 11:18:57.413 INFO 8 --- [ main] s.c.a.i.c.AzureSpringBootVersionVerifier : Cannot check Boot version from manifest

Copy 2023-02-22 11:18:57.433 INFO 8 --- [ main] s.c.a.i.c.AzureSpringBootVersionVerifier : Cannot check Boot version from manifest

Copy 2023-02-22 11:18:58.234 INFO 8 --- [ main] c.a.c.i.jackson.JacksonVersion : Package versions: jackson-annotations=unknown, jackson-core=unknown, jackson-databind=unknown, jackson-dataformat-xml=unknown, jackson-datatype-jsr310=unknown, azure-core=1.26.0, Troubleshooting version conflicts: https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/dependency/troubleshoot

Copy 2023-02-22 11:18:59.476 INFO 8 --- [ main] AbstractAzureServiceClientBuilderFactory : Will configure the default credential of type DefaultAzureCredential for class com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder.

Copy 2023-02-22 11:19:02.634 INFO 8 --- [ main] lambdainternal.AWSLambda : Started AWSLambda in 39.898 seconds (JVM running for 45.01)

Copy 2023-02-22 11:19:02.714 INFO 8 --- [ main] c.a.s.p.i.servlet.AwsServletContext : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

Copy 2023-02-22 11:19:02.732 INFO 8 --- [ main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'

Copy 2023-02-22 11:19:02.735 INFO 8 --- [ main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Completed initialization in 2 ms

Copy START RequestId: ef81158e-cf35-4803-9f6c-a9812c544eb8 Version: $LATEST

Copy 2023-02-22 11:19:03.216 DEBUG 8 --- [ main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy : Securing GET /

Copy 2023-02-22 11:19:03.294 DEBUG 8 --- [ main] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext

Copy 2023-02-22 11:19:03.355 DEBUG 8 --- [ main] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext

Copy 2023-02-22 11:19:03.453 DEBUG 8 --- [ main] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /] with attributes [authenticated]

Copy 2023-02-22 11:19:03.473 DEBUG 8 --- [ main] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request

Copy 2023-02-22 11:19:03.475 INFO 8 --- [ main] c.a.s.p.internal.LambdaContainerHandler : 127.0.0.1 null- null [09/04/2015:12:34:56Z] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 - "-" "Custom User Agent String" combined

maven dependency:

```
<artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
```

application.properties file:

```
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.enabled=true
spring.cloud.azure.activedirectory.client-id= url
spring.cloud.azure.activedirectory.client-secret=url
spring.cloud.azure.activedirectory.app-id-uri=url
spring.cloud.azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=url
jwk.provider.uri= url
```

Class has configure method which is extending AadResourceServerWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
```

I tried to authenticate using correct token in aws lamdba console but always I am getting 401. Please refer above logs.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: check network, authentication & Azure AD configuration

Comment: After created a minimal reproducible example, I suggest you create an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues